# WCF WSDL Generation Details on How and what each section means

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wcf-client

I'm quiet new to WCF world.

I've been looking and trying to understand the WSDL file being generated by WCF. the reason I'm looking is that our clients with Java and PHP are having issue importing the WSDL.

Could anyone please kindly help me with following queries:

```
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:13818/WCFService2/Service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:13818/WCFService2/Service.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:13818/WCFService2/Service.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EvalServiceLibrary" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
```

Query 1

Based on what condition is above import schemalocation tags gets generated? Is it based on number of data contracts and members or somethingelse (what is it?)

```
- <wsdl:message name="IEvalService_SubmitEval_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitEval" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IEvalService_SubmitEval_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitEvalResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
```

Query 2:
I don't have any message name IEvalService_SubmitEval_InputMessage. How is above being generated? Also what is part name and element?

```
 <wsdl:portType name="IEvalService">
- <wsdl:operation name="SubmitEval">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IEvalService/SubmitEval" message="tns:IEvalService_SubmitEval_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IEvalService/SubmitEvalResponse" message="tns:IEvalService_SubmitEval_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
```

Query 3:

could yo uplease tell me what is "tns:IEvalService_SubmitEval_InputMessage" on above wsdl snippet?

Fianally:

```
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org
/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
```

is thre any way to remove the above unnecessary namespace from WCF code? I only know how to change the namespace.

Thank you heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This part depends on number of assemblies involved. The first line represents your service assembly, second line is always included - that some MS predefined elements (but still valid interoperable XSD) and the third line is probably library with your data contracts.
2. The default pattern is ServiceContractName_OperationContractName_X where X is either InputMessage or OutputMessage to differ between request and response. Part defines content of the message and element is reference to XSD scheme - that element will be defined in first or second schema import from your first question.
3. `tns` probably stands for target namespace - it is a prefix of elements defined in your WSDL document. It is just reference to message defined in your second question.
4. With default stuff no. You would probably need custom encoder.

What errors do your clients have when importing the WSDL? All these parts are valid.

Comment: Thank you heaps @Ladislav Mrnka, very helpful. What sort of refrence do you use to master above and WCF as whole?

Comment: WSDL is standardized, WS-Policies are standardized and XSD is standardized as well. You can either read specifications or simply learn from WSDL you have to use (as I did). Default naming conventions are scattered in MSDN but they are usually intuitive once you see them.